# ASP.NET share same session with .aspx page in IFream

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application, where one controller returns a View that have an `iframe` , controller also returns url that need to loaded.

I need that  `iframe` to load legacy `.aspx` pages.

Now I want to share some data from MVC controller to that `.aspx` page via 'SESSION' or 'Request' object.

Is it possible ? Do I have any other alternative  to share data securely (I don't want to pass as get parameters).

Comment: You can add querystring to url of `.aspx` page .

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to pass as params in GET request ...  it will be less secure.

Comment: If MVC controller and .aspx page are in two different applications then you can not share data via sessions or any other way....

Comment: Of course you can. You just can't through the `SESSION`. Session sharing through DB or distributed persistent storages have been done millions of times.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are talking about two different applications, there are some options but none through `SESSION`

Your first issue is how to identify the same user. There are two options here.

1. Through the use of cookies, if both applications are in the same domain. You can store a session identifier there and it will be sent to both applications. A jwt token would do fine or any other session identifier
2. Through the use of a single sign on system. This would be more tricky to implement and there are a lot of oauth/openidconnect systems out there to choose from.

Now onto the session iteself. Since we are talking about two applications, you are going to need some kind of shared place to store the session values

- The simplest form would be a shared database where you store the session values. It could be in memory tables in mssql to speed things up. On the downside, you should be careful to invalidate/update the values which would cost in queries
- Some kind of distributed cache, like REDIS.

**Warning** - You might see suggestions to use session state store. This is to share `SESSION` between servers and not so easily between applications, so I wouldn't suggest that.